# Framerate drops in all games on Intel HD Graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, intel

I am experiencing serious framerate drops (down to around 2-4fps) in all games on my **Thinkpad T420** with **Intel HD Graphics 3000**.
The games I've tried have been both very high and very low demand games on both ultra high and ultra low settings, the results are the same.

I am told that there is **no need to install proprietary drivers** for the Intel cards, as they are included in the kernel, which I would love to believe, but it really seems to be a driver issue.
The problems occur with native drivers both on **Ubuntu 14.04.3** and on **Ubuntu 15.10** in both **awesome wm** and **Gnome 3**.

I have tried a few things:

1. **intel-linux-graphics-installer** (couldn't install)
   This GUI installer can be downloaded from here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/
   They only support the latest unstable Ubuntu, and all links to previous versions are broken.
   I managed to fetch a copy of the 1.0.7 version, which was supposed to support Ubuntu 14.04.3, but still rejected my distro during the install.
2. **xorg-xserver-video-intel** (breaks the system beyond my ability to repair)
   I got recommended the above mentioned package, but as soon as I installed it and rebooted, gdm wouldn't start, and switching to tty in order to uninstall the package didn't solve it either.
   I had to reinstall the system to get it back.

Does anyone here have a similar experience with this card or machine?
Thanks in advance!

**Output of inxi -Fxz:**

`System:    Host: tor Kernel: 3.19.0-42-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.8.2)
           Desktop: Awesome 3.4.15 Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
Machine:   System: LENOVO product: 4180AV8 version: ThinkPad T420
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 4180AV8 Bios: LENOVO version: 83ET66WW (1.36 ) date: 10/31/2011
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-2520M CPU (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9967.86
           Clock Speeds: 1: 800.00 MHz 2: 799.902 MHz 3: 800.00 MHz 4: 800.00 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           X.Org: 1.17.1 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1600x900@60.0hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Sandybridge Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.9 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card: Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: k3.19.0-42-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection driver: e1000e ver: 2.3.2-k port: 5080 bus-ID: 00:19.0
           IF: eth0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] driver: iwlwifi ver: in-tree: bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: wlan0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 160.0GB (15.7% used) 1: id: /dev/sda model: INTEL_SSDSA2BW16 size: 160.0GB
Partition: ID: / size: 47G used: 5.1G (12%) fs: ext4 ID: /home size: 92G used: 19G (22%) fs: ext4
           ID: swap-1 size: 8.47GB used: 0.02GB (0%) fs: swap
RAID:      No RAID devices detected - /proc/mdstat and md_mod kernel raid module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 51.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 3589
Info:      Processes: 188 Uptime: 2 days Memory: 1431.0/7867.0MB Runlevel: 2 Gcc sys: 4.8.4
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.11) inxi: 1.9.17`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem on my T420. In my case, everything is fine at first. After playing for a few minutes, the notebook gets hot and the framerate drops. The same symptomps show, when playing HD flash videos.

After spending numerous hours searching online for answers I stumbled upon an article in the [Thinkwiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_HD_Graphics):

> The following boot options may help considerably with power:
>   i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.semaphores=1 pcie_aspm=force

Adding these boot options has resolved the issue for me, this is how you do it:

> sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

... add options to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT ...

> sudo update-grub

... restart the system